# How do I make a Jquery Accordion collapsed when I'm redirected to my page

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've got an accordion on my page and I want to have all 4 panes closed, how would I do this, does it have anything to do with this piece of code?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

My example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wUR6F/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for all the panes to be collapsed, you also have to specify `false` in the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) option:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wUR6F/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The `collapsible: true` allows the accordion to be collapsed.

To make it start off so all 4 panels are closed you can add `active:false`

See a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wUR6F/2/)